# SQL(ite) Making List to 2D Table converting rows to columns

Tags: sql, select, sqlite

**Original Question**

I have a table containing a list values for a combination of two attributes:

```
Pattern | Feature | Value
--------+---------+-------
 P1     | F1      | V1.1
 P1     | F2      | V1.2
 P2     | F1      | V2.1
 P2     | F2      | V2.2
```

I'd like to convert the table so, that the "Features" became column names:

```
Pattern | F1      | F2
--------+---------+-------
 P1     | V1.1    | V1.2
 P2     | V2.2    | V2.2
```

Is that possible with pure SQL? I'd prefere SQLite, but could use MySQL or PostgreSQL also.

Many thanks!

**Extended after JW.'s answer**

I didn't mention another column containing instances. As I thought, it was not important.
One instance can be assigned to only one pattern but contain many features.

```
   Instance | Pattern | Feature | Value
   ---------+ --------+---------+-------
     In1    | P1      |  F1     | V1.1.1
     In1    | P1      |  F2     | V1.1.2
     In2    | P1      |  F1     | V2.1.1
     In2    | P1      |  F2     | V2.1.2
     In3    | P2      |  F1     | V3.2.1
     In3    | P2      |  F2     | V3.2.2
     In4    | P2      |  F1     | V4.2.1
     In4    | P2      |  F2     | V4.2.2
```

The instance itself is not important in resulting table, but the resulting table should contain one row for every instance. (It's tor feeding SVM engine)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  Pattern,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Feature = 'F1' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS F1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Feature = 'F2' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS F2
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY Pattern
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/8356e/1)

Comment: +1: Thank you! But I wonder, why it should be any list to scalar conversion like MAX, MIN, AVG (tried out these ones)? Couldn't the table contain many rows for each Patern-Features combination? May be my example was misleading. I'm going to extend it.